# Code Igniter File upload

Tags: codeigniter, file-upload

I am uploading images from two separate views so in autoload under libraries, I have included **upload**.

I have a file called upload.php in config. From this I am passing parameters like size,file type etc.

```
          if( ??){
        $config['upload_path'] = realpath('x');
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif';
$config['max_size'] = '1048';
$config['max_width']  = '1024';
$config['max_height']  = '768';
          }
           else{
        $config['upload_path'] = realpath('x');
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif';
$config['max_size'] = '1048';
$config['max_width']  = '1024';
$config['max_height']  = '768';


              }
```

Now since there are two places where  I upload, I have a different file size, type parameters, How do my controller know which one to take. What should I put in if{} else {] condition.

Let me know, If I am not not clear.

Comment: In that case you should set the values for the config array in your controller, not via config/upload.php.

Comment: you could use a hidden input field in each view with a different value and have the if else check for that

Comment: @John B:How do I that ? Can you give me a small snippet.My upload.php is under config folder so will your thing work.

Comment: the input will be in the view file on the html form and will post with the file when the form is submitted

Comment: @ram Just following up, I posted some detailed answers to you earlier questions.  Please review and let me know if you sorted things out.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In upload.php

```
 $config['first']['upload_path'] = realpath('x');
    $config['first']['allowed_types'] = 'gif';
    $config['first']['max_size'] = '1048';
    $config['first']['max_width']  = '1024';
    $config['first']['max_height']  = '768';
```

Similarily for second

```
 $config['second']['upload_path'] = realpath('x');
....
..
```

and In controller

```
$this->load->config('upload_values', TRUE);

$upload_values = $this->config->item('first');

$this->load->library('upload', $upload_values);
```

Comment: What is $this->load->config('upload_values', TRUE); upload_values in this. What is the best practices for max_width and max_height allowed in web applications.

Comment: I think that depends on the purpose of the image being uploaded.

Comment: :What is $this->load->config('upload_values', TRUE); upload_values in this.

Comment: upload_values is the config file we put into upload library  $this->config->item('first'); will put first array values in config file

Comment: @Aruna:upload_values is the config file not clear.Is it file name or what ?

Comment: @Aruna: Did you test your code, I get an error saying path is not correct.I only added two dimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has to do a few things:

(1) You need to set a flag (hidden variable is a good way) in each upload form so that you
know which folder to store the file in.  Let's call this flag `upload_target`

In your controller:

(2) Get `upload_target` from the post variables

(3) Depending on the value `upload_target`, set the upload_config values as needed
    and then load/initialize the upload class.

**Where to put the `upload_config` values**
**If you try to define a 2-dimensional array in config/upload.php, the library loader will probably get confused.**

Instead, define a config file called `upload_settings.php` and define the following arrays:

```
$config['target1']['upload_path'] = './uploads_path_1/';
$config['target1']['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
$config['target1']['max_size']  = '100';
$config['target1']['max_width']  = '1024';
$config['target1']['max_height']  = '768';

$config['target2']['upload_path'] = './uploads_path_2/';
$config['target2']['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
$config['target2']['max_size']  = '100';
$config['target2']['max_width']  = '1024';
$config['target2']['max_height']  = '768';
```

In your upload controller, you will do something like:

```
$this->config->load('upload_settings', TRUE);
```

Depending on the value of `upload_target` that you got from the form's post variable:

```
$upload_config_values = $this->load->config('target1','upload_settings');
```

or

```
$upload_config_values = $this->load->config('target2','upload_settings');
```

You can now load or initialize your upload class:

```
$this->load->library('upload', $upload_config_values);
```

I wrote this up as meta-code to give you an outline of a feasible approach.

**Setting Up the Hidden Value Flag/Parameter**
For each form that you are using to upload files, add a hidden value as follows.
For the first form:

and for the second form:

Get the `upload_target` value from post variables and pick the correct configuration file based on the value.

Comment: :I get this error The upload path does not appear to be valid. I am putting 'upload' in autoload.php. I did not under stand hidden value thing, what should I put in value, name.<input type="hidden" name="?" value="?" >

Comment: Can you update your question and post your `config/upload.php`, I want to see what the path and settings look like.  I added an explanation about the hidden value in my answer.

Comment: Echo out `realpath('./x/images')` and double check the path.  Is folder `x` in your root directory or outside? The `./` could be the issue.