# Code igniter resize()

Tags: codeigniter

I am using resize() to resize the thumbnail. My source image is 1024 * 768. This is my config

```
 $demo= array(
                  'source_image' => $x['full_path'],
                  'new_image' => $this->image,
                  'maintain_ratio' => true,
                  'create_thumb' => true,
                  'width' => 192,
                  'height' => 92
                );
```

But my image is getting resized to 123 * 98. Why is it not using the width value ?

Answer (score 2):

You have enabled the `maintain_ratio` option, so CI will try to create the thumbnail that is as "close to the target width and height as possible while preserving the original aspect ratio".

In your case you have an image with dimensions 1024x768, aspect ratio is 1.33854 (1024/768).

This corresponds to a 192x143 thumbnail or a 123x92 thumbnail using your specified values for width and height.

CI decides that 123x92 is a closer fit (probably based on area of the thumbnail).

Why 123x98? probably some artifact of the resizing algorithm (math round off errors?).

One would need to look at the CI code details for a more precise answer.

**Footnote**
There is some discussion about image resizing in CI, there are some quirks in the module:

```
[quote author="Saete" date="1346125636"]You will not beleive me, 
y had the same problem and y changed the order of configuration parameters 
with the maintain_ratio = true, and it worked :S
I needed to adjust to height:

Didn't work:
$config['width'] = 126;
$config['height'] = 84;
$config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;

Worked!
$config['height'] = 84;
$config['width'] = 126;
$config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;

Some years later, but it may help someone...[/quote]
```

apparently, the order of the parameters makes a difference (a bug for sure).
Reference: http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/119169/#594586

Comment: Okay. How do i get 123 * 98 ?

Comment: I see where the 123 came from, I am guessing about 98.

Comment: You could adjust width/height so that the aspect ratio of the thumbnail is closer to that of the input image and see if the results differ.

Comment: I did a bit of research and found a discussion on the Ellis Lab forum.

Comment: How do others achieve the width and height that they prefer.Is there any alternate to image_lib function.Image that user upload will be different size but I want thumbnail in the size I mention.Thanks for taking time to answer to my question.

Comment: You could try using PHP's native image processing library.  You could write you own Library function within CI, a bit more work but quite doable.  See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

Comment: :Can you answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15505702/code-igniter-file-upload

Comment: Be happy to take a quick look.  I would appreciate an up vote on this answer, thanks!